# Do's & Don'ts for Island traveling?

Tags: animal-crossing-new-leaf

Anyone got a list of things what you can bring for the island later on in the game and items you have to leave behind?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't take *anything* to the island except what you're wearing. No tools or items of any sort except clothing items that you are currently wearing. Note that wetsuits you are currently wearing count as clothes (so you can take them) but can still be used as tools on the island. Though this isn't a huge advantage as you can rent a wetsuit on the island anyway.

Tools instead will be provided by a Gyroid at the island and on each of the tours. You can take any non-tour related item back to your town by leaving it in the basket in the hut when you first reach the island. All other items will be sold at an extremely low price when you go home or go on a tour.

Comment: Can you currently wear an umbrella? Or you have to leave that behind as well?

Comment: You can take a wetsuit to the island if you're wearing it, in that instance it counts as clothing rather than a tool (It's kind of got tool functionality as it lets you do something specific).

Comment: @GraemeHunter good point I've noticed that as well, added.

Comment: @spongefan12 Umbrellas are equipment, so you automatically put it away when boarding Kapp'n's boat. It's left behind with your other inventory.